# Violating foreign key constraint with deferred constraint

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to set my sql scripts into a transaction to achieve atomicity with my database.

The table structure is (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id serial  NOT NULL,
    foo varchar(50)  NOT NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT foo_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE access (
    id serial  NOT NULL,
    foo_id int  NULL
    CONSTRAINT access_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE access ADD CONSTRAINT access_foo
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_id)
    REFERENCES foo (id)
    ON DELETE  CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE  CASCADE 
    DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

In my code I first declare: 
`client.query('BEGIN');` (I'm using npm library 'pg') then
insert a row into a table 'foo', then another insert to 'access' with a foo_id from the first insert. After that there is `client.query('COMMIT');`

All of this is in a try catch, and in the catch is `client.query('ROLLBACK');` and the rolling back seems to be working if there is an issue either of the inserts. When everything should be committed I still end up in the catch block for this:

**message: "insert or update on table "access" violates foreign key constraint "access_foo""**

**detail: "Key (foo_id)=(20) is not present in table "foo"."**

I thought that deferring constraint would be enough to do this, but I guess I'm wrong. Any help is welcome.

Comment: `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` in PostgreSQL validates the foreign key constraint at the end of the transaction. I would guess there's something wrong with your transaction demarcation.

Comment: There is literally verything you need to know in the error message: Key (foo_id)=(20) is not present in table "foo"
So you are inserting into access foo_id=20 but in to there is no row with id=20. Most likely your INSERT INTO fee fails.

Comment: Note that you can't `DELETE` a parent record and then re-insert it before committing,  when children are present. I learned it the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some issue with the transaction demarcation. I ran a simple test and works wells.

```
insert into foo (id, foo) values (1, 'Anne');

start transaction;

insert into access (id, foo_id) values (101, 1);

insert into access (id, foo_id) values (107, 7); -- 7 does not exist yet...

insert into foo (id, foo) values (7, 'Ivan'); -- 7 now exists!

commit; -- at this point all is good
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ccwkTJM532bLkP4h7kfgbJ/0).

Comment: Thanks, this guided me to the right direction and I found my problem. I didn't use pg pool correctly.